# Definition of the equality refered by the definition of a partial order

Tags: definition, order-theory, equivalence-relations

A partial order $≤$ on a set $P$ must satisfy the following properties:

1. **Reflexivity:** For all $a \in P$, $a ≤ a$
2. **Anti-symmetry:** For all $a,b \in P$, $a ≤ b \land b ≤ a → a = b$
3. **Transitivity:** For all $a,b,c \in P$, $a ≤ b \land b ≤ c → a ≤ c$

But regarding the anti-symmtery, what equivalence relation does $=$ mean? Does it have to be the finest equivalence relation on $P$, or can it be coarser? Say, if $P$ is the set of triangles on the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$:

- Usually, $=$ denotes the equality of the area of the triangles.
- There is also $≡$, which denotes the congruence of the triangles. This is also an equivalence relation.
- On the extreme, triangles could be considered equivalent only if the have exact same set of coordinates of vertices.

It is practical to define order over the $=$. It would sort triangles on their area. Defining order over the extreme equivalence would make lexicographical ordering of triangles. And I don't see a practical order relation over the $≡$.

So which equivalence relation does a partial order refer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a=b$ means $a$ and $b$ are the same element of $P$. If you want to put a partial order on the set of equivalence classes of $P$ (under some other equivalence relation) then you can do that. Then anti-symmetry has the same interpretation but in the set of equivalence classes.

Comment: So the partial order is in the partition, not in the original $P$. Is there a term for the original relation in $P$? Like "weak partial order" or something?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. If you partially order $P$ then antisymmetry means that $a$ and $b$ are literally the same if they are both greater than each other. If you order some other set (which could be a set of equivalence classes on $P$), then the same thing applies in that set.

Comment: I mean, if $P = \{a,b_1,b_2\}$, what is a term for relation $\{(a,a),(a,b_1),(a,b_2),(b_1,b_1),(b_1,b_2),(b_2,b_1),(b_2,b_2)\}$? It is a "weak partial order" that treats $b_1$ and $b_2$ equivalent but not same.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. That's an order satisfying reflexivity and transitivity but not antisymmetry. Usually those are called preorders.